# Проблемы с Virtual Box и Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: ubuntu, virtualbox

Столкнулся со следующей проблемой.

Когда открываю некоторые диалоги в `Ubuntu` (например, `Менеджер приложений Ubuntu`), то содержимое окна обновляется кусками, на которые наводится мышь. При этом, старые куски изображения остаются в окне до тех пор, пока на их месте (попиксельно) не отрисуются новые элементы. А они не отрисуются, пока на них не навести мышь.

Кто виноват, `Ubuntu` или `Virtual Box`?

Какие варианты лечения существуют?

Comment: Скорее всего баг где-то между виртуалбоксом и графическим драйвером, который он использует. На родном драйвере и реальном железе такое маловероятно и в крайнем случае на реальном железе можно попробовать другой драйвер.

Comment: Попробуйте в настройках дисплея выбрать графический контроллер VBoxVGA, если выбран другой

Comment: Установить  `Virtual box additions` в `/media` и выполнить `VBoxLinuxAdditions.run` не забыли?

Comment: @avp, забыл, спасибо.

Comment: @andreymal, смена графического контроллера на `VBoxVGA` помогла решить сразу две проблемы. Во-первых, исчезли залипания изображения внутри `Ubuntu`. Во-вторых, разрешение экрана в `Ubuntu` теперь подстраивается под размер окна на хосте. Спасибо вам.

Answer (score 2):

Были похожие проблемы с Ubuntu в VirtualBox, решилось всё классическим пересозданием виртуальной машины и выделением большего количества видеопамяти в настройках и оперативной памяти при установке. Настройки виртуальной машины -> Дисплей и там можно выделить больше видеопамяти и поменять видеоадаптер(возможно тот, что по умолчанию, не совместим с вашей версией Ubuntu).

Comment: Интересный лайфхак, в VirtualBox можно отхватить больше видеопамяти чем он дает, надо выбрать: Дисплей -> Экран -> Количество мониторов -> тут выбираешь максимальное количество мониторов -> меняешь память на максимальную -> нажимаешь ок -> заходишь повторно и меняешь количество мониторов на нужное. И заместь 128 Мб у тебя 256 Мб :)